# Visual Studio Code runs extremely slow when I import any library such as Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pycharm, anaconda

I installed both Anaconda3 and Visual Studio code.
When I execute a simple code via Python ('Root':conda) and import a library such as Pandas it takes ~ 20 seconds to run.

I installed Pycharm and got the same slow result when tried to execute it via conda Python.

The code is:

```
Import Pandas as pd
Print ("Hello World")
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Could you tell me which platform you use?

Comment: This is an informed guess… With Visual Studio Code comes extensions that help with different languages.  One of the installed extension on your machine handles Python code.  Such an extension does more than colouring the code.  It loads and indexes libraries included in your project, ready to provide you detailed information about a Class or a function.  Pandas is a huge package. So, once the extension is aware of the existence of pandas in your project, its documentation is loaded in memory. That has an impact on the performance of the editor.

Comment: a side comment: your code is not a valid Python3 code (`Import`, `Pandas`, `Print`). Is it intentional?